# Paring a variable length dot separated string in grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am new with logstash and grok filters.  I am trying to parse a string from an Apache Access Log, with a grok filter in logstash, where the username is part of the access log in the following format:

```
name1.name2.name3.namex.id
```

I want to build a new field called USERNAME where it is name1.name2.name3.namex with the id stripped off.  I have it working, but the problem is that the number of names are variable.  Sometimes there are 3 names (lastname.firstname.middlename) and sometimes there are 4 names (lastname.firstname.middlename.suffix - SMITH.GEORGE.ALLEN.JR

```
%{WORD:lastname}.%{WORD:firstname}.%{WORD:middle}.%{WORD:id}
```

When there are 4 names or more it does not parse correctly. I was hoping someone can help me out with the right grok filter.  I know I am missing something probably pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could use two patterns, adding another one that matches when there are 4 fields:

```
%{WORD:lastname}.%{WORD:firstname}.%{WORD:middle}.%{WORD:suffix}.%{WORD:id}
```

But in this case, you're creating fields that it sounds like you don't even want.

How about a pattern that splits off the ID, leaving everything in front of it, perhaps:

```
%{DATA:name}.%{INT}
```